# Data to jsonObject to Data to Struct is it possible?

Tags: json, swift

I know it sounds complicated, but let me explain.

Im getting the following json data from a webservice:

```
{
   "code": 200,
   "object": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Peter"
   }
}
```

So, i turn that into a jsonObject, then i want to "extract" the object to a "Person" struct

```swift
import Foundation

struct Person : Decodable {
    var id : Int
    var name : String
}

let data = """
{
    "code": 200,
    "object": { //this can be any object
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Peter"
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
        if json["code"] as! Int == 200 {
            var object = json["object"] as! Data
            
            do {
                let person = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: object)
                print(person.name)
            } catch { print(error) }
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Maybe there is an easier way to do it, i don't know im new to swift and i haven't found much information about this.

I would appreciate any suggestions or comments about this procedure.

Comment: Just make a Codable struct that is your “ResponseObject” and decode that with the original data. You should be able to use responseObject.object

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the problem i have with that is that how i point out, the varaible "object" in the json response, is not tied to Person, it can be different object or structs, i would have to make a Response struct for EACH struct i have in my project for that

Comment: @PedroJoaquín _"the problem i have with that is that how i point out, the varaible "object" in the json response, is not tied to Person, it can be different object or structs"_ hehe, called it! (_"but I'm reading between the lines and assuming that you're calling several related endpoints of an API, which each return wrappers of different kinds of object."_ in my comment below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a mix of `JSONSerialization` (which is the older, Foundation/Objective-C API) and Swift's Codable, you can do this all with Codable:

```swift
import Foundation

struct APIResponse<Payload: Decodable>: Decodable { // FIXIME: Name me better
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case statusCode = "code"
        case payload = "object"
    }
    
    let statusCode: Int
    let payload: Payload
}

struct Person: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}


let data = """
{
    "code": 200,
    "object": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Peter"
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse<Person>.self, from: data)

guard response.statusCode == 200 else {
    // TODO: handle non-happy cases, raise an error, or whatever
}

let person = response.payload
print(person.name) // => Peter
```

Here I'm using a new type, `APIResponse`, which models the outter object that wraps the `Person`. I made it generic, assuming that this kind of structure can hold one of several different kinds of payload types (depending on what's being queried from a server). For your example, I'm using `APIResponse<Person>`.

Comment: Just to properly understand, in the line where you decode the data the APIResponse<Person>, the diamond can be replazable? for example APIResponse<Animal>, would it work?

Comment: @PedroJoaquín Yes. I was cautious to use that because you might not be "there" yet, but I'm reading between the lines and assuming that you're calling several related endpoints of an API, which each return wrappers of different kinds of object. `APIResponse` is a _generic_ type, meaning it behaves _as if_ there one `APIResponse` type per possible value of its `Payload` generic type parameter (`Person`, `Animal`, ...). It imposes the constraint that whatever the `Payload` is, it needs to be `Decodable` (for the rest of the code to work).

Comment: @PedroJoaquín For a relatable example, Cconsider `Array<Int>` vs `Array<String>`. Array is generic over its `Element`, allowing you to have different kinds of arrays depending on what you want to store in them. For more info, see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics/

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the code above throws the following errors: on the guard line says: "Cannot assing to property 'response' is a 'let' constant.. if i change response to var it throws: "Use of '=' in a boolean context, did you mean '=='?

Comment: @PedroJoaquín I did mean `==` :) I'm checking that the code is actually 200 (HTTP OK) rather than some other error code.